# new thread causes "Method Name Expected" error

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm trying to call buildRangedJobCache with SelectionRange S as the passed in parameter, But the Compiler(visual studio 2010) gives the error: `Method Name Expected` below is the call that gives issue:

```
    private void retrieveSeveralDaysJobs(SelectionRange S)
    {
        ignoreUpdates = false;
        this.SetStatus(DataLogUIStrings.strRetrievingJobInformation);
        Thread buildIndexThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(buildRangedJobCache(S)));
        buildIndexThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
        buildIndexThread.Start();
    }
```

and here is the function buildRangedJobCache(SelectionRange S):

```
    private void buildRangedJobCache(SelectionRange S)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.AppStarting;
        try
        {                
            if (DataStore == null)
            { throw new Exception("Error: DataStore is null, Unable to retrieve jobs."); }
            lock (((ICollection)jobs).SyncRoot)
            {
                for (DateTime Day = S.Start; Day <= S.End; Day.AddDays(1))
                {
                    this.RangeJobs.AddRange(DataStore.GetJobsListForDay(JobDateToDisplay.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Today)));
                }
            }
            this.SetStatus(string.Format(DataLogUIStrings.strRetrievedSummaryInformation, this.jobs.Count));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Write(e);
        }
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

also I've linked to here: [Delegate: Method name expected error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309708/delegate-method-name-expected-error)
as this solution didn't work for me.

**update: apparently it isn't clear, the solution of putting:

```
Thread buildIndexThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(buildRangedJobCache));
```

does the same issue.

Comment: You still get the error when you remove the parens and the parameter S?  The problem is you're invoking the method in your constructor to ThreadStart, not passing the method name.  Also, are you constrained to using threads, or can you make use of the newer Tasks library?  I think it's a little easier to understand and work with.  You might want to check that out.

Comment: constrained to threads

Comment: Adding to what @Maurice said Creating a thread is costly operation within OS , so would be better if we use QueueUserWorkItem or Task classes because this takes the thread from the thread pool (threads are already created and maintained in this pool) so when you dont have any limitation of using types you can consider using these types to improve the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass only method name when creating delegate:

```
Thread buildIndexThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(buildRangedJobCache));
```

Also [ThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx) delegate should not receive any arguments. It is defined as

```
 public delegate void ThreadStart();
```

So, your `buildRangedJobCache` method signature do not match `ThreadStart` delegate signature. If you want to pass some parameters to thread, you should use [ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx) delegate, which accepts parameter of type `object`:

```
private void retrieveSeveralDaysJobs(SelectionRange range)
{
    ignoreUpdates = false;
    this.SetStatus(DataLogUIStrings.strRetrievingJobInformation);
    // pass ParameterizedThreadStart delegate
    Thread buildIndexThread = new Thread(BuildRangedJobCache);
    buildIndexThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
    buildIndexThread.Start(range); // provide parameter for thread
}

private void BuildRangedJobCache(Object obj)
{
    SelectionRange range = (SelectionRange)obj; // cast to your type
    // code
}
```

Comment: You can do a ParameterizedThreadStart to pass parameters to the method you're invoking.  But that's different than the pattern you're using above.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx

Comment: @DarthSheldon I've added complete solution with explanations

Comment: @lazyberezovksy - I saw that.  We came in at the same time.  :-D  All credit to you for your complete answer.  Cheers.

Comment: @MauriceReeves :) sorry then

Answer (score 1):

The `Thread` constructor requires a delegate (either `ThreadStart` or `ParametrizedThreadStart`). You're trying to create the `ThreadStart` delegate, but you can create a delegate out of a *method*, not method invocation expression.

So, if your method didn't have a parameter, the following would work:

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(buildRangedJobCache));
```

and so would (because the compiler can infer which delegate are you creating):

```
new Thread(buildRangedJobCache);
```

If you need to pass a parameter to your method, you can use `ParametrizedThreadStart` and the overload of `Start()` that takes a parameter. But this means you have to change your method to have `object` parameter and cast it to your type inside the method.

I think a better option would be to use a lambda:

```
new Thread(() => buildRangedJobCache(S));
```

This creates an anonymous method that matches `ThreadStart` and remembers the variable `S`. This way, you don't need the signature of your method and you also don't need any casting.