# Getting compile time error while creating threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am new to threading in C#. What I want to do is that I am getting some events for screens from API. Now I want to run those events together on my primary and secondary screen. Here is the code snippet.

```
private void btn_play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var path = "C:\\ActiveProjects\\ScreenPlayerClient\\ScreenPlayerClient\\" +
        "ScreenPlayerClient\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.1\\Json\\eventsfile.json";
    var events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetEventsResponseModel>(
        File.ReadAllText(path));
    var screens = Screen.AllScreens;
    foreach (var scr in events.Screens)
    {
        foreach (var computerscreen in screens)
        {
            if (scr.Title == computerscreen.DeviceName)
            {
                Thread thr = new Thread(
                    new ThreadStart(playContent(scr, computerscreen)));
            }
        }
    }
}

private void playContent(ScreenResponseModel scr, Screen screen)
{
    var fileDetails = apiOperation.DownLoadFile(
        scr.Events.FirstOrDefault().VideoLink).Result;
    var filepath = SaveVideo(fileDetails);
    PlayerForm player = new PlayerForm();
    player.videolink = filepath;
    player.Location = screen.WorkingArea.Location;
    player.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    player.screen = screen;
    player.ShowDialog();
}
```

I am getting error *"Method Name Expected"* at

```
Thread thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(playContent(scr,computerscreen)));
```

Comment: Why are you using raw threads instead of `Task.Run`? Besides, you can't modify the UI (including UI components) from a background thread in any OS. It looks like the only thing that actually needs to run in the background is `apiOperation.DownLoadFile` and maybe `SaveVideo(fileDetails);`. What do those methods do? You can probably turn them into asynchronous methods so you won't need an extra thread at all

Comment: Isn't it similar to this article? [new thread causes "Method Name Expected" error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17195341/9014308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> playContent(scr,computerscreen)

this calls a function. `new Thread` expects a ThreadStart delegate, or something that can be converted to a delegate, i.e. a lambda or a method name.

Try changing it to

> new Thread(() => playContent(scr,computerscreen));

However, I would argue for using Tasks rather than raw threads. There is almost never a good reason for creating a `Thread` yourself. I.e.

> Task.Run(() => playContent(scr,computerscreen));

However, it looks like `playContent` is doing something UI related, and that will simply not work. Or it may create multiple UI threads, and that is rarely a good idea. UI classes can only be accessed from the associated UI thread. So I would reconsider the whole plan of using threads in the first place.

Comment: I am Quite new to threading and tasks. I am downloading video links to run on my screens. First it download the file saves it to local disk and then play on respective screen on repeat. Here what you suggest how i can do it simultaneously for N number of screens.

Comment: @Malik Mehmood My recommendation would be to stay away from multi threading unless you are familiar with the risks. It should work perfectly fine to update multiple windows from a single UI thread, so start with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread thr = new Thread(() => playContent(src,computerscreen));
thr.Start();
```

Comment: could you explain your answer beyond postin code only ?